# Create agent and give its population different id/names and stop each id delay on different time

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent

I have an agent and set its parameter **Name** and give 3 different names

[image]

What I want to do is stop the delay of each name on a different calendar date. How I can achieve that?

Comment: please accept my solution as answer if it solved your issue. This would help others with the same question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current year, month and day with the following functions:

`int getYear(Date date)` — returns the year of the current date.

`int getMonth(Date date)` — returns the month of the current date: one of the constants JANUARY, FEBRUARY, etc.

`int getDayOfMonth(Date date)`— returns the day of the month of the current date: 1, 2, …

Based on these, you can get the first agent in the delay block with `delay.get(0)` and use if function.

Pseudo-code like this;

```
if (date==x){
    if (delay.get(0)==myAgents.get(0)){
       stopDelay(delay.get(0));
}
}
```

or

```
if (date==x){
    if (delay.get(0).Name=="yyy"){
       stopDelay(delay.get(0));
}
}
```